# Webview is reloaded sometimes and Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog'

Tags: xcode, webview

Here my error, please help me

1. [ProcessSuspension] 0x11401c240 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS Background assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process because PID 0 is invalid
2. [ProcessSuspension] 0x11401c240 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=0, error: (null)
3. WebPageProxy::processDidTerminate: (pid 2453), reason=Crash
4. WebPageProxy::dispatchProcessDidTerminate: reason=Crash
5. GPUProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit
6. WebProcessProxy::gpuProcessExited: reason=IdleExit
7. Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

Comment: you don't provide enough context

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error on iOS using leaflet with the plugin "edgebuffer" which cause this bug when I unzoom the map.
Finally decided not to use it as it crashes the map.

But maybe your error is due to something completely different as you didn't give any context.